# Assigning IP to a small office network

Tags: static-ip

I need to assign static ip address to a network with the following specification:

- There are 6 set(12 nos.) of sub-networks.
- Each set has a Primary and a Redundant network loops with Server having Win-2003 server and clients with Win-XP

Now I need the best ip config for a connection that makes the communication in-between all 6 network clients and servers.
Also I need to learn regarding what the 4 fields in ip are for, the best practice to use all the 4 fields and how modifying a fields affects communication. Please suggest a link for a beginner where I can learn these.

Comment: What routing and switchgear do you have available to you to make this happen?

Comment: Start here.  http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work

Comment: Multi-cast i think. Client we have need to connect to server at regular intervals(1sec) to retrive data for an application. Which server to connect is defined in client, and communication will be between these two. More than 1 client will be connected to the server

Comment: Looks like a textbook homework question to me.

Comment: -1, If this is homework, you need to pickup the assigned book and start reading. Your understand of IP is substantially lacking, and this kind of effort is going to hurt you come test time. If this is really for a business, you need to call a consultant who knows what they're doing.

Comment: @Zoredache - Thanks a lot I think I got a great doc to read about IP's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For how the network address is constructed I'd suggest you read up on [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR) and [routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing).  I'd also suggest you talk to whoever designed your network about IP addressing in case their primary/redundant design has some particular requirements.  I'd also suggest that if you are inexperienced then you're not a good choice for implementing what seems to be a very complex design.

That all said, I'd suggest you construct the addresses as follows:

```
10.a.b.x/24
```

For each of your 6 networks take 2 numbers as the `a` field to represent the primary and redundant IP ranges (for example, `100` and `200`) and 6 consecutive numbers (for example, 100 to 106) as the `b` field to represent the sub-networks.

This should make it easy to expand the design if required in the future, and easy to identify what network a particular IP belongs to.

---

How, or if, the communication works depends on how routing is configured.  That's entirely in control of whoever configures the routers.

Oh, and multicast is not a kind of router or switch ;)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I need to know if the ip 10.100.106.12 can communicate with 10.100.105.13? Also if a primary's ip can communicate with the redundant?